# Remove Shadow of Action Bar from a Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml

I tried this

```
getActionBar().setElevation(0);
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

None seems to work.

Only worked when I put

```
app:elevation="0dp"
```

in the app_bar_main.xml

But I want to hide the shadow from only for UserProfile fragment.

Is there any way to do it programmatically?

I'm using import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity so few functions I found on other posts are not working.

Comment: Just get the `AppBar` with `findViewById` and set it `appbar.setElevation(0);`.

Comment: I tried all of them for 3-4 hours, couldn't get to work. That's why I posted to help from you guys.

Comment: @Tahmid I would suggest to create UserProfile an activity and use Toolbar without AppBarLayout

Comment: But I need shadows on other fragments.